# Dynamic URL Goal Set up in Google Analytics

Tags: dynamic-pages

I need to to set up goal in Google Analytic:-

Step 1: /PaymentAddress?prodID=171364

Step 2: /order-step3.php?prodID=171364

Step 3: /thank-you-page.php

Please suggest me how can i set up goal for these dynamic page urls.

Comment: Just use regex matching. Show us some effort and we can help guide you,  also give more info on what parts are dynamic.

Comment: Is this Correct:-                                                                                        Step 1: ^\/PaymentAddress\?prodID   

Step 2: ^\/order-step3\.php

Step 3: Step 3: /thank-you-page.php

Answer (score 0):

You need to qualify the dynamic portions of the URLs:

Step 1: ^/PaymentAddress\?prodID=.*

Step 2: ^/order-step3.php\?prodID=.*

Step 3: ^/thank-you-page.php

Comment: All right. is there any way to verify above regex matches are correct. Do i need implement this on Google Funnel path section>

Comment: Just verify in your real time reports after you set them up in your goal funnel.

Comment: Product id is dynamic and change every time according to the selected product by user. for example

Comment: can you explain how can i use this on real time reports. actually i never do this before.

Comment: Sure, you need to configure your Goal from the View tab in the GA admin page, and then observe conversions through RT reports under Conversions. https://analytics.googleblog.com/2013/05/see-your-conversions-in-real-time.html